# Execute my jQuery script after dynamically inserted jQuery library has finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onload, jquery-events

I am dynamically inserting the jQuery library on a page via `<script>` tag:

```
jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.setAttribute('src','//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js');
b.appendChild(jq);
```

Then I have some jQuery script that needs to run after the jQuery library has finished loading and is ready for use:

```
$(f).load(function() {
    $(f).fadein(1000);
});
```

How can I make it wait for jQuery to load?

Comment: Rob's answer below is perfect, though let me shimmy on here that what you're doing is (a good) part of what Modernizr was made for. :D

Answer (score 14):

Specify an `onload` event at the to-be-inserted script tag:

```
function onLoad() {
    $(f).load(function() {
        $(f).fadein(1000);
    });
}

jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.onload = onLoad;   // <-- The magic
jq.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
b.appendChild(jq);
```

An alternative way, if you cannot control the script insertion code, you can use a poller:

```
(function() {
    function onLoad() { ... } // Code to be run

    if ('jQuery' in window) onLoad();
    else {
        var t = setInterval(function() { // Run poller
            if ('jQuery' in window) {
                onLoad();
                clearInterval(t);        // Stop poller
            }
        }, 50);
    }
})();
```